# Is rr and at results the same?

Tags: r, machine-learning, optimization, mlr3

I'm studying some models of machine learning and currently optimizing the models :
I have to compare these algos on my validation set to select the best one.
I use two methods with mlr3 (the code here is an example) :

1)

```
learner_svm = lrn("classif.svm", type = "C-classification", cost = to_tune(p_dbl(1e-5, 1e5, logscale = TRUE)), gamma = to_tune(p_dbl(1e-5, 1e5, logscale = TRUE)), kernel = to_tune(c("polynomial", "radial")), degree = to_tune(1, 4), predict_type = "prob")

learner_rpart = lrn("classif.rpart", cp = to_tune(0.0001,1),  minsplit = to_tune(1, 60),  maxdepth = to_tune(1, 30), minbucket = to_tune(1,60), predict_type = "prob")

learner_xgboost = lrn("classif.xgboost", predict_type = "prob", nrounds = to_tune(1, 5000), eta = to_tune(1e-4, 1, logscale = TRUE), subsample = to_tune(0.1,1), max_depth = to_tune(1,15), min_child_weight = to_tune(0, 7), colsample_bytree = to_tune(0,1), colsample_bylevel = to_tune(0,1), lambda = to_tune(1e-3, 1e3, logscale = TRUE), alpha = to_tune(1e-3, 1e3, logscale = TRUE))

learner_kknn = lrn("classif.kknn", predict_type = "prob", k = to_tune(1, 30))

learner_ranger = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type = "prob", num.trees = to_tune(1, 2000), mtry.ratio = to_tune(0, 1), sample.fraction = to_tune(1e-1, 1), importance = "impurity")

learner_glmnet = lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type = "prob")

set.seed(1234)
at_xgboost = auto_tuner(
  tuner= tnr("random_search"),
  learner = learner_xgboost,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_tuning_instance = TRUE,
  store_models = TRUE
)

set.seed(1234)
at_ranger = auto_tuner(
  tuner= tnr("random_search"),
  learner = learner_ranger,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_tuning_instance = TRUE,
  store_models = TRUE
)

set.seed(1234)
at_rpart = auto_tuner(
 tuner= tnr("random_search"),
  learner = learner_rpart,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_tuning_instance = TRUE,
  store_models = TRUE
)

set.seed(1234)
at_svm = auto_tuner(
 tuner= tnr("random_search"),
  learner = learner_svm,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_tuning_instance = TRUE,
  store_models = TRUE
)

at_glmnet = auto_tuner(
  tuner= tnr("random_search"),
  learner = learner_xgboost,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_tuning_instance = TRUE,
  store_models = TRUE
)

measures = msrs(c("classif.auc", "classif.bacc", "classif.bbrier"))

learners = c(lrn("classif.featureless"), at_rpart, at_ranger, at_xgboost, at_svm, at_glmnet)

set.seed(1234)
design = benchmark_grid(
  tasks = task, 
  learners = learners,
  resamplings = resampling_outer)
 bmr = benchmark(design,store_models = TRUE)
 
 results <- bmr$aggregate(measures)
 print(results)
 
archives = extract_inner_tuning_archives(bmr)
inner_learners = map(archives$resample_result, "learners")
```

To better understand the code :
-data = my native normalized dataset.
-task = my data with my target : "LesionResponse"
-resampling outer = I divide my whole dataset in train (comprising train + validation) and test.
-resampling inner = I divide my train into train and validation (for hyper-parameters optimization).

Here I use the auto tuning with an extraction of the results for my validation set in order to compare them.
I extract the best results for each learner and put it in a table.

2. My second method is the following one :

```
set.seed(1234)
#Auto tuning elastic net
learner_glmnet = lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type = "prob")
measure = msr("classif.auc")

rr_glmnet = tune_nested(
  tuner = tnr("random_search"),
  task = task,
  learner = learner_glmnet,
  inner_resampling = resampling_inner,
  outer_resampling = resampling_outer,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_models = TRUE,
  terminator = trm("none")
)

glmnet_results<-extract_inner_tuning_results(rr_glmnet)[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("learner_param_vals", "x_domain")]

set.seed(1234)
#Auto tuning Ranger
learner_ranger = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type = "prob", num.trees = to_tune(1, 2000), mtry.ratio = to_tune(0, 1), sample.fraction = to_tune(1e-1, 1), importance = "impurity")

rr_ranger = tune_nested(
  tuner = tnr("random_search"),
  task = task,
  learner = learner_ranger,
  inner_resampling = resampling_inner,
  outer_resampling = resampling_outer,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_models = TRUE,
  terminator = trm("none")
)

ranger_results<-extract_inner_tuning_results(rr_ranger)[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("learner_param_vals", "x_domain")]

set.seed(1234)
#Auto tuning knn
learner_kknn = lrn("classif.kknn", predict_type = "prob", k = to_tune(1, 30))

rr_kknn = tune_nested(
  tuner = tnr("random_search"),
  task = task,
  learner = learner_kknn,
  inner_resampling = resampling_inner,
  outer_resampling = resampling_outer,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_models = TRUE,
  terminator = trm("none")
)

kknn_results<-extract_inner_tuning_results(rr_kknn)[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("learner_param_vals", "x_domain")]

set.seed(1234)
#Auto tuning xgboost
learner_xgboost = lrn("classif.xgboost", predict_type = "prob", nrounds = to_tune(1, 5000), eta = to_tune(1e-4, 1, logscale = TRUE), subsample = to_tune(0.1,1), max_depth = to_tune(1,15), min_child_weight = to_tune(0, 7), colsample_bytree = to_tune(0,1), colsample_bylevel = to_tune(0,1), lambda = to_tune(1e-3, 1e3, logscale = TRUE), alpha = to_tune(1e-3, 1e3, logscale = TRUE))

rr_xgboost = tune_nested(
  tuner = tnr("random_search"),
  task = task,
  learner = learner_xgboost,
  inner_resampling = resampling_inner,
  outer_resampling = resampling_outer,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_models = TRUE,
  terminator = trm("none")
)

xgboost_results<-extract_inner_tuning_results(rr_xgboost)[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("learner_param_vals", "x_domain")]

set.seed(1234)
#Auto tuning rpart
learner_rpart = lrn("classif.rpart", cp = to_tune(0.0001,1),  minsplit = to_tune(1, 60),  maxdepth = to_tune(1, 30), minbucket = to_tune(1,60), predict_type = "prob")

rr_rpart = tune_nested(
  tuner = tnr("random_search"),
  task = task,
  learner = learner_rpart,
  inner_resampling = resampling_inner,
  outer_resampling = resampling_outer,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_models = TRUE,
  terminator = trm("none")
)

rpart_results<-extract_inner_tuning_results(rr_rpart)[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("learner_param_vals", "x_domain")]

set.seed(1234)
#Auto tuning svm
learner_svm = lrn("classif.svm", type = "C-classification", cost = to_tune(p_dbl(1e-5, 1e5, logscale = TRUE)), gamma = to_tune(p_dbl(1e-5, 1e5, logscale = TRUE)), kernel = to_tune(c("polynomial", "radial")), degree = to_tune(1, 4), predict_type = "prob")

rr_svm = tune_nested(
  tuner = tnr("random_search"),
  task = task,
  learner = learner_svm,
  inner_resampling = resampling_inner,
  outer_resampling = resampling_outer,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_models = TRUE,
  terminator = trm("none")
)

svm_results<-extract_inner_tuning_results(rr_svm)[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("learner_param_vals", "x_domain")]
```

I pick up the results for the inner resampling optimization and put it in a table.
Problem : Are these methods giving the same results (I basically do the same things finally...) ? No and I don't understand why...
With the first method, I have the wgboost giving me the best results, and for the second one, it is the svm with different auc...

EDIT : Concerning the results obtained, here is two tables, the first one is the results with the first method
[image: First dataset]

And then the results with the second method [image: Second dataset]

It's a little embarrassing since I must choose the best model to test on my test set

EDIT : Lars gave me the answer, it was all the result of hazard and seed...

Next question is : How to have a confidence interval in this particularly case ??

Comment: You won't get exactly the same results when running even the same thing twice. Are the results close? If so, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Yes indeed I think so, concerning the results I'll add an edit with two tables for the results

Comment: You could try running everything again with a different random seed and see whether the differences you get with that are in line with the differences you're seeing for the different chunks of code.